# Why is my own app incompatible with my phone?

Tags: google-play

I have made an app, and tested it fully on my phone. When I uploaded it to the market, it says it is incompatible with my phone - why is this, and is there any way to manually include my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that because I had set my app to use the protection (App-Private data folder), it wouldn't be installed to rooted phones. My phone is rooted.